# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error just randomly occurred

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, sqlite, syntax-error

The code that I have been working with as a fun side project has been working perfectly fine until when running the search function I uncounted an error which I have never had before. I've tried to figure out why it ain't working because in the past it has and all of a sudden it isn't.

```
import sqlite3

def connect():
    """Set up a connection with the database."""
    conn_obj = sqlite3.connect("movies.db")
    cur_obj = conn_obj.cursor()
    cur_obj.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
                    "movie (id integer PRIMARY KEY, "
                            "title text, "
                            "director text, "
                            "year integer, "
                            "studio integer)")
    conn_obj.commit()
    conn_obj.close()

def insert(title, director, year, studio):
    """Insert entry into database."""
    conn_obj = sqlite3.connect("movies.db")
    cur_obj = conn_obj.cursor()
    cur_obj.execute("INSERT INTO movie "
                    "VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (title, director, year, studio))
    conn_obj.commit()
    conn_obj.close()

def view():
    """View all database entries."""
    conn_obj = sqlite3.connect("movies.db")
    cur_obj = conn_obj.cursor()
    cur_obj.execute("SELECT * FROM movie")
    rows = cur_obj.fetchall()
    conn_obj.close()
    return rows

def update(id, title, author, year, isbn):
    """Update a database entry."""
    conn_obj = sqlite3.connect("movies.db")
    cur_obj = conn_obj.cursor()
    cur_obj.execute("UPDATE movie "
                    "SET title = ?, "
                    "director = ?, "
                    "year = ?, "
                    "studio = ? "
                    "WHERE id = ?", 
                    (title, director, year, studio, id))
    conn_obj.commit()
    conn_obj.close()

def delete(id):
    """Delete a database entry."""
    conn_obj = sqlite3.connect("movies.db")
    cur_obj = conn_obj.cursor()
    cur_obj.execute("DELETE FROM movie "
                    "WHERE id = ?", (id,))
    conn_obj.commit()
    conn_obj.close()

def search(title = "", director = "", year = "", studio = ""):
    """Search for a database entry."""
    conn_obj = sqlite3.connect("movies.db")
    cur_obj = conn_obj.cursor()
    cur_obj.execute("SELECT * "
                    "FROM movie "
                    "WHERE title = ? OR director = ? OR year = ? OR studio = ?", 
                    (title, director, year, studio))
    rows = cur_obj.fetchall()
    conn_obj.close()
    return rows

connect()
```

This is the backend of the code which mainly deals with the backbones of the code whereas the frontend deals with the tkinter GUI. The problem lies in line 68 of the backend of the code which is apart of the search function due to an error near ?. To paraphrase the problem lies with this line of code (title, director, year, studio, runtime, rtscore, id)) because of a 
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error

```
from tkinter import *
import backend
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import re
import webbrowser
def add_command():
    """Insert entry via button."""
    backend.insert(title_text.get(),
                    director_text.get(),
                    year_text.get(),
                    studio_text.get(),
                    runtime_text.get(),
                    rtscore_text.get())
    listing.delete(0, END)
    listing.insert(END, 
                    (title_text.get(), 
                    director_text.get(), 
                    year_text.get(), 
                    studio_text.get(),
                    runtime_text.get(),
                    rtscore_text.get()))

def view_command():
    """View entries via button."""
    listing.delete(0, END)
    for row in backend.view():
        listing.insert(END, row)

def update_command():
    """Update entry via button."""
    backend.update(selected_tuple[0], 
                    title_text.get(), 
                    director_text.get(), 
                    year_text.get(), 
                    studio_text.get(),
                    runtime_text.get(),
                    rtscore_text.get())

def delete_command():
    """Delete entry via button."""
    backend.delete(selected_tuple[0])

def search_command():
    """Search entry via button."""
    listing.delete(0, END)
    for row in backend.search(title_text.get(), 
                                director_text.get(), 
                                year_text.get(), 
                                studio_text.get(),
                                runtime_text.get(),
                                rtscore_text.get()):
        listing.insert(END, row)


def get_selected_row(event):
    """Pre-fill fields for selected entry."""
    global selected_tuple
    index = listing.curselection()[0]
    selected_tuple = listing.get(index)

    entry1.delete(0, END)
    entry1.insert(END, selected_tuple[1])
    film = selected_tuple[1]
    entry2.delete(0, END)
    entry2.insert(END, selected_tuple[2])

    entry3.delete(0, END)
    entry3.insert(END, selected_tuple[3])

    entry4.delete(0, END)
    entry4.insert(END, selected_tuple[4])

    entry5.delete(0, END)
    entry5.insert(END, selected_tuple[5])

    entry6.delete(0, END)
    entry6.insert(END, selected_tuple[6])

def get_trailer():
    global selected_tuple
    index = listing.curselection()[0]
    selected_tuple = listing.get(index)
    film = selected_tuple[1]
    year = selected_tuple[3]
    years = str(year)
    print(year)
    print(film)
    query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode({"search_query" : film + years + 'trailer'})
    html_content = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.youtube.com/results?" + query_string)
    search_results = re.findall(r'href=\"\/watch\?v=(.{11})', html_content.read().decode())
    web = ("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + search_results[0])
    print(web)
    webbrowser.open(web)


window = Tk()

window.wm_title("Film Directory")

# Labels for entry fields.
label1 = Label(window, text = "Title")
label1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

label2 = Label(window, text = "Director")
label2.grid(row = 0, column = 2)

label3 = Label(window, text = "Year")
label3.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

label4 = Label(window, text = "Studio")
label4.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

label5 = Label(window, text = "RunTime")
label5.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

label6 = Label(window, text = "RtScore")
label6.grid(row = 2, column = 2)

# Entry Fields.
title_text = StringVar()
entry1 = Entry(window, textvariable = title_text)
entry1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

director_text = StringVar()
entry2 = Entry(window, textvariable = director_text)
entry2.grid(row = 0, column = 3)

year_text = StringVar()
entry3 = Entry(window, textvariable = year_text)
entry3.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

studio_text = StringVar()
entry4 = Entry(window, textvariable = studio_text)
entry4.grid(row = 1, column = 3)

runtime_text = StringVar()
entry5 = Entry(window, textvariable = runtime_text)
entry5.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

rtscore_text = StringVar()
entry6 = Entry(window, textvariable = rtscore_text)
entry6.grid(row = 2, column = 3)

# List all data.
listing = Listbox(window, height = 6, width = 35)
listing.grid(row = 2, column = 0, rowspan = 6, columnspan = 2)

# Scrollbar.
scroller = Scrollbar(window)
scroller.grid(row = 2, column = 2, rowspan = 6)

# Configure scrollbar for Listbox.
listing.configure(yscrollcommand = scroller.set)
scroller.configure(command = listing.yview)

listing.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', get_selected_row)

# Buttons for various operations on data.
button1 = Button(window, 
                text = "View All", 
                width = 12, 
                command = view_command)
button1.grid(row = 3, column = 3)

button2 = Button(window, 
                text = "Search Entry", 
                width = 12, 
                command = search_command)
button2.grid(row = 4, column = 3)

button3 = Button(window, 
                text = "Add Entry", 
                width = 12, 
                command = add_command)
button3.grid(row = 5, column = 3)

button4 = Button(window, 
                text = "Update Selected", 
                width = 12, 
                command = update_command)
button4.grid(row = 6, column = 3)

button5 = Button(window, 
                text = "Delete Selected", 
                width = 12, 
                command = delete_command)
button5.grid(row = 7, column = 3)

button6 = Button(window, 
                text = "Close", 
                width = 12, 
                command = window.destroy)
button6.grid(row = 8, column = 3)

button7 = Button(window, 
                text = "Trailer", 
                width = 12, 
                command = get_trailer)
button7.grid(row = 9, column = 3)


# Keep window open until closed.
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: There's no `title, director, year, studio, runtime, rtscore, id` in the code you posted.

Comment: Python code isn't compiled by default. You need to test every part of your code yourself. At runtime, if a piece of code isn't called, then it doesn't have to be bug-free.

Comment: Please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The Gui is updated with runtime and rt_score entries, yet
your backend using the database access was not.

I updated and fixed as with limited testing and you can
fix any outstanding or get further help.

I set runtime column as text in the database and you can
change the type if not suitable.

In the main tk script, an error occurs in function
`get_selected_row`. I added a temporary fix as tk probably
needs a setting to avoid the issue. See the script comment.

You may need to recreate or alter the existing database file as
backend.py will create and use a table with 2 more columns.

**tk script**

```
from tkinter import *
import backend
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import re
import webbrowser
def add_command():
    """Insert entry via button."""
    backend.insert(title_text.get(),
                    director_text.get(),
                    year_text.get(),
                    studio_text.get(),
                    runtime_text.get(),
                    rtscore_text.get())
    listing.delete(0, END)
    listing.insert(END,
                    (title_text.get(),
                    director_text.get(),
                    year_text.get(),
                    studio_text.get(),
                    runtime_text.get(),
                    rtscore_text.get()))

def view_command():
    """View entries via button."""
    listing.delete(0, END)
    for row in backend.view():
        listing.insert(END, row)

def update_command():
    """Update entry via button."""
    backend.update(selected_tuple[0],
                    title_text.get(),
                    director_text.get(),
                    year_text.get(),
                    studio_text.get(),
                    runtime_text.get(),
                    rtscore_text.get())

def delete_command():
    """Delete entry via button."""
    backend.delete(selected_tuple[0])

def search_command():
    """Search entry via button."""
    listing.delete(0, END)
    for row in backend.search(title_text.get(),
                                director_text.get(),
                                year_text.get(),
                                studio_text.get(),
                                runtime_text.get(),
                                rtscore_text.get()):
        listing.insert(END, row)


def get_selected_row(event):
    """Pre-fill fields for selected entry."""
    global selected_tuple
    # *** unsure fix to avoid index out of range error.
    # *** callback issue when double click in a input ctrl.
    if not listing.curselection(): return

    index = listing.curselection()[0]
    selected_tuple = listing.get(index)

    entry1.delete(0, END)
    entry1.insert(END, selected_tuple[1])
    film = selected_tuple[1]
    entry2.delete(0, END)
    entry2.insert(END, selected_tuple[2])

    entry3.delete(0, END)
    entry3.insert(END, selected_tuple[3])

    entry4.delete(0, END)
    entry4.insert(END, selected_tuple[4])

    entry5.delete(0, END)
    entry5.insert(END, selected_tuple[5])

    entry6.delete(0, END)
    entry6.insert(END, selected_tuple[6])

def get_trailer():
    global selected_tuple
    index = listing.curselection()[0]
    selected_tuple = listing.get(index)
    film = selected_tuple[1]
    year = selected_tuple[3]
    years = str(year)
    print(year)
    print(film)
    query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode({"search_query" : film + years + 'trailer'})
    html_content = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.youtube.com/results?" + query_string)
    search_results = re.findall(r'href=\"\/watch\?v=(.{11})', html_content.read().decode())
    web = ("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + search_results[0])
    print(web)
    webbrowser.open(web)


window = Tk()

window.wm_title("Film Directory")

# Labels for entry fields.
label1 = Label(window, text = "Title")
label1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

label2 = Label(window, text = "Director")
label2.grid(row = 0, column = 2)

label3 = Label(window, text = "Year")
label3.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

label4 = Label(window, text = "Studio")
label4.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

label5 = Label(window, text = "RunTime")
label5.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

label6 = Label(window, text = "RtScore")
label6.grid(row = 2, column = 2)

# Entry Fields.
title_text = StringVar()
entry1 = Entry(window, textvariable = title_text)
entry1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

director_text = StringVar()
entry2 = Entry(window, textvariable = director_text)
entry2.grid(row = 0, column = 3)

year_text = StringVar()
entry3 = Entry(window, textvariable = year_text)
entry3.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

studio_text = StringVar()
entry4 = Entry(window, textvariable = studio_text)
entry4.grid(row = 1, column = 3)

runtime_text = StringVar()
entry5 = Entry(window, textvariable = runtime_text)
entry5.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

rtscore_text = StringVar()
entry6 = Entry(window, textvariable = rtscore_text)
entry6.grid(row = 2, column = 3)

# List all data.
listing = Listbox(window, height = 6, width = 35)
listing.grid(row = 2, column = 0, rowspan = 6, columnspan = 2)

# Scrollbar.
scroller = Scrollbar(window)
scroller.grid(row = 2, column = 2, rowspan = 6)

# Configure scrollbar for Listbox.
listing.configure(yscrollcommand = scroller.set)
scroller.configure(command = listing.yview)

listing.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', get_selected_row)

# Buttons for various operations on data.
button1 = Button(window,
                text = "View All",
                width = 12,
                command = view_command)
button1.grid(row = 3, column = 3)

button2 = Button(window,
                text = "Search Entry",
                width = 12,
                command = search_command)
button2.grid(row = 4, column = 3)

button3 = Button(window,
                text = "Add Entry",
                width = 12,
                command = add_command)
button3.grid(row = 5, column = 3)

button4 = Button(window,
                text = "Update Selected",
                width = 12,
                command = update_command)
button4.grid(row = 6, column = 3)

button5 = Button(window,
                text = "Delete Selected",
                width = 12,
                command = delete_command)
button5.grid(row = 7, column = 3)

button6 = Button(window,
                text = "Close",
                width = 12,
                command = window.destroy)
button6.grid(row = 8, column = 3)

button7 = Button(window,
                text = "Trailer",
                width = 12,
                command = get_trailer)
button7.grid(row = 9, column = 3)


# Keep window open until closed.
window.mainloop()
```

**backend.py script**

```
import sqlite3

def connect():
    """Set up a connection with the database."""
    conn_obj = sqlite3.connect("movies.db")
    cur_obj = conn_obj.cursor()
    cur_obj.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
                    "movie (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                            "title TEXT,"
                            "director TEXT,"
                            "year INTEGER,"
                            "studio INTEGER,"
                            "runtime TEXT,"
                            "rt_score INTEGER)")
    conn_obj.commit()
    conn_obj.close()

def insert(title, director, year, studio, runtime, rt_score):
    """Insert entry into database."""
    conn_obj = sqlite3.connect("movies.db")
    cur_obj = conn_obj.cursor()
    cur_obj.execute("INSERT INTO movie "
                    "(title,director,year,studio,runtime,rt_score) "
                    "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
                    (title, director, year, studio, runtime, rt_score))
    conn_obj.commit()
    conn_obj.close()

def view():
    """View all database entries."""
    conn_obj = sqlite3.connect("movies.db")
    cur_obj = conn_obj.cursor()
    cur_obj.execute("SELECT * FROM movie")
    rows = cur_obj.fetchall()
    conn_obj.close()
    return rows

def update(id, title, director, year, studio, runtime, rt_score):
    """Update a database entry."""
    conn_obj = sqlite3.connect("movies.db")
    cur_obj = conn_obj.cursor()
    cur_obj.execute("UPDATE movie "
                    "SET title = ?, "
                    "director = ?, "
                    "year = ?, "
                    "studio = ?, "
                    "runtime = ?, "
                    "rt_score = ? "
                    "WHERE id = ?",
                    (title, director, year, studio, runtime, rt_score, id))
    conn_obj.commit()
    conn_obj.close()

def delete(id):
    """Delete a database entry."""
    conn_obj = sqlite3.connect("movies.db")
    cur_obj = conn_obj.cursor()
    cur_obj.execute("DELETE FROM movie "
                    "WHERE id = ?", (id,))
    conn_obj.commit()
    conn_obj.close()

def search(title="", director="", year="", studio="", runtime="", rt_score=""):
    """Search for a database entry."""
    conn_obj = sqlite3.connect("movies.db")
    cur_obj = conn_obj.cursor()
    cur_obj.execute("SELECT * "
                    "FROM movie "
                    "WHERE title = ? "
                    "OR director = ? "
                    "OR year = ? "
                    "OR studio = ? "
                    "OR runtime = ?"
                    "OR rt_score = ?",
                    (title, director, year, studio, runtime, rt_score))
    rows = cur_obj.fetchall()
    conn_obj.close()
    return rows

connect()
```

Comment: I know of the selected tuple error, but for some reason it works perfectly fine so I decided if it ain't broke don't fix it

Comment: Shit, I just noticed I uploaded the wrong code hence why in the backend rtscore was missing

Comment: You have some comparing to do now. Perhaps something learned and something fixed. Suggest you use a versioning system like i.e. [fossil](http://fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) or git to keep your source organized if not already.

Comment: @BenjaminLawrence You _can_ replace your code on the question by [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48052766/edit)ing.